# Memory corrupted crash analysis

Tags: c++, assembly, gdb, crash-dumps

This question is to get ideas. So basically we have run into a particular crash, where the backtrace is meaningless above some frame. This is from an ARM based binary. We were unable to reproduce the issue yet, which hardens the analysis. Some observations first:

- Nearly all the required libraries' unstripped shared libraries are available so the backtrace should be ok normally
- However, the backtrace points on frame 3 to a memory address, which is clearly not in the code segment
- That problematic memory address is also visible in some argument parameters
- Register info shows unaligned address on R3 register. Disassemble shows that stmia ASM operation on it, which was the root cause - it caused sigbus.

All in all, this is because of a corrupted memory, stack, etc. I have only limited information right now. I want to trace back at least where this call came, but because of the corruption, I am now not really able to find it.

Do you have any ideas, how to proceed which such problems? Any tools, which can help me to analyze the assembly flow and data and registers in a better environment, maybe seeing the stack, etc in a more intuitive way? Much thanks in advance!

EDIT: To be a bit more precise: how would you try to find out what was above frame 2? Is it possible in some scenarios to decode it back, even though the stack was somehow corrupted? Or finding out what corrupted it?

EDIT2: i think i will debug that function and I saw a particular log line before  the crash. I will place a breakpoint and check where the calls are coming, albeit it is a very generic méthod, plus the initialization functions' orders are really fuzzy. Have no other clue. Do you have some "intuitive reading ASM level data from core file" tool idea?

Comment: Consider using a tool like `valgrind` to track down the memory corruption.

Comment: We are already using these. Now that you say, maybe I will run it down again, but I think we have already checked for the latest findings and none of them points to invalid writes, etc. I would rather try to inquire here tools , which helps me when we have only postmortem data and there is no way that we can reproduce the issue. - which is sadly very common where I work currently.

Comment: Hm... that sucks a little. Also consider using the various hardening and sanitation features if you are using gcc or clang.

Comment: GDB can record history and let you rewind (single-step backwards).  It's of course very slow while single-stepping + recording.  I haven't used it, but it might be useful if you can reproduce the crash without running very long:  https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Process-Record-and-Replay.html

Comment: The device is ARM jacinto 6, so the GDB is a bit more limited than the linux ones. I will definitely check these out too, though these are still requires that we need to reproduce the issue.

Comment: You could check the code for places where the last valid function in the backtrace is called from. If you are lucky, it's only one or a few places so you can then continue the backtrace based on that. If you are unlucky it was a call through a pointer that you won't easily find.

Comment: These are obvious, and for beginners Jester. That function which is on frame 2 can be called from millions of places. I have a similar idea for next week though.

Comment: Do not forget that it could be a hardware issue.

Comment: I don't care the case, when it is a hardware problem, all I want is an answer for the question above: how to analyze such problems when we assume, that it is our fault and the situation is like the aforementioned.